# Error: returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am attempting to debug an app that I created using `kivy`.

I am using `buildozer` and running the command `buildozer osx debug`.

However, I am getting this error message:

```
   CalledProcessError: Command '['python', 'package_app.py', '/Users 
   /Documents/.buildozer/osx/app',
  '--appname=musicalapp', '--bundlename=Music Favorites',
  '--bundleid=my_app.test', '--bundleversion=1.0',
  '--displayname=Music Favorites']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you place your entire arguments in quotes, you also need to quote the 2-word arguments, i.e.

```
'--bundlename="Music Favorites"'
```